# Calculating Mu (Friction Coefficient) vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I've been working on a vehicle braking distance calculator in vb.net but I've run into a problem where the equation isn't giving the correct answer. The math for getting Mu is to multiply the speed the car is going at in m/s by 2 then divide by 2 multiplied by the final weighted factor of the car multiplied again by gravity which is 9.81. The part of the code causing problems is below.

```
    Dim i As Double
    Dim o As Double
    Dim z As Double
    Dim v As Double
    Dim sU As Double
    Dim wU As Double
    Dim fU As Double
    Dim G As Double = 9.81
    Dim brakeArray = {2.0, 1.6, 1.3, 1.0, 0.7, 0.4}

    If cboRoad.SelectedIndex = 0 And rdaWno.Checked Then
        sU = 0.75
    ElseIf cboRoad.SelectedIndex = 0 And rdaWyes.Checked Then
        sU = 0.6
    ElseIf cboRoad.SelectedIndex = 1 And rdaWno.Checked Then
        sU = 0.6
    ElseIf cboRoad.SelectedIndex = 1 And rdaWyes.Checked Then
        sU = 0.45
    ElseIf cboRoad.SelectedIndex = 2 And rdaWno.Checked Then
        sU = 0.4
    ElseIf cboRoad.SelectedIndex = 2 And rdaWyes.Checked Then
        sU = 0.26
    End If
```

(sU is the standard U)

```
    If cboBrakes.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        wU = brakeArray(0)
    ElseIf cboBrakes.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        wU = brakeArray(1)
    ElseIf cboBrakes.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
        wU = brakeArray(2)
    ElseIf cboBrakes.SelectedIndex = 3 Then
        wU = brakeArray(3)
    ElseIf cboBrakes.SelectedIndex = 4 Then
        wU = brakeArray(4)
    ElseIf cboBrakes.SelectedIndex = 5 Then
        wU = brakeArray(5)
    End If
```

(wU is the weighting factor of the car)

```
    v = vSpeedMS

    fU = sU * wU
    i = v * 2
    o = 2 * fU * G
    z = i / o
```

I have tried braking the equation up into smaller pieces but that hasn't helped, along with seraching for an answer on my own but with no luck.

Comment: Please explain the problem you're having your code, and if you are getting errors, explain which ones, and where they occur.

Comment: I'm not getting any actual errors it's just the answer getting outputted is wrong e.g. if a veichle is going 25 m/s with a standard U of 0.6 and a weigting U of 2 then then the equation is 25 * 2 / 2 * 1.2 * 9.81 which should give a braking distance of 26.546 but the answer i'm getting is 2.123

Comment: If the math isn't working out, perhaps you should look into http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Additionally, you may want to rethink your formula. 25*2/2*1.2*9.81=294.3

Comment: Brackets are your friends...

Comment: The calculation that your code is doing is v * 2 / (2 * sU * wU * G) which is 25 * 2 / (2 * 0.6 * 2 * 9.81) which does indeed equal approximately 2.123. You must be doing the wrong calculation, I can't think of a way to reorganise the brackets to get 26.546 as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have misread the formula for braking distance, according to [Wikipedia's Braking Distance article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braking_distance) it is v ^ 2 / (2 * fU * G). That is v squared rather than v multiplied by 2 as the first term. If you change the last section of code to the following, your should get the answer you expected (26.546).

```
v = vSpeedMS
z = v ^ 2 / (2 * sU * wU * G)
```

Here is code for a function (a shorter version of your code) that will return stopping distance for any given speed. If no values are selected in the ComboBoxes, an error message is displayed, and the function returns a negative number.

```
Function StoppingDistance(vSpeedMS As Double) As Double 
    Const G As Double = 9.81
    Dim brakeArray() As Double = {2.0, 1.6, 1.3, 1.0, 0.7, 0.4}

    If cboBrakes.SelectedIndex < 0 Or cboRoad.SelectedIndex < 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Select items for Brakes and Road")
        Return Double.MinValue 
    End If

    Dim fU As Double = brakeArray(cboBrakes.SelectedIndex)

    If cboRoad.SelectedIndex = 0 And rdaWno.Checked Then
        fU *= 0.75
    ElseIf cboRoad.SelectedIndex = 0 And rdaWyes.Checked Then
        fU *= 0.6
    ElseIf cboRoad.SelectedIndex = 1 And rdaWno.Checked Then
        fU *= 0.6
    ElseIf cboRoad.SelectedIndex = 1 And rdaWyes.Checked Then
        fU *= 0.45
    ElseIf cboRoad.SelectedIndex = 2 And rdaWno.Checked Then
        fU *= 0.4
    ElseIf cboRoad.SelectedIndex = 2 And rdaWyes.Checked Then
        fU *= 0.26
    End If  

    Return vSpeedMS ^ 2 / (2 * fU * G)
End Function
```